# calling a method on a button

Tags: cocoa

is it the right way to call a method named "inserttable" on a button "gobtn" , in whitch method is declared in a appdelegate?

```
gobtn= [[UIButton alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self  action:@selector(inserttable:)];
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you're trying to do? I don't think I understand...

Comment: Instead of `[UIButton alloc]`, did you mean `[UIBarButtonItem alloc]`?  UIButton does not have an initWithTitle method.

Answer (score 0):

So i think you want this button to call `-(void)inserttable{}` which is a delegates method?

one way is

```
gobtn= [[UIButton alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self  action:@selector(inserttable)]; // without the colon if the method takes no parameters..

-(void)inserttable
{
//Do what stuff you want
.
.
[appdelegate inserttable];// or this if you intend on passing the buttons action to call
                         //inserttable of the appdelegate. 
}
```

or

```
gobtn= [[UIButton alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:adddelegate  action:@selector(inserttable)]; // without the colon if the method takes no parameters..
```